# Best location for a reusable helper method in Rails 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I plan to create a method that would format a Time in a specific way (specialized formatting in Russian).

I would like to reuse this helper method in multiple models, controllers and possibly views. Also I would like to call this helper method on instance of Time class like follows:

```
t=Time.now
t.my_super_shiny_helper
```

Question: where should I implement this helper? (module or class, where in application directory structure?). After creating it, how should I call it?

I'm new to ruby/rails and struggle to get this working in a proper way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would add a file to `lib/time_extensions.rb`

```
class Time
  def my_shiny_helper
    ...
  end
end
```

And in an initializer file in `config/intitializers`

```
require 'time_extensions'
```

If the extensions grow a bit and are something you want to reuse think of putting it into a plugin for easy inclusion.  Or even a gem.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to format a time, a clean approach in Rails (as given in Agile Web Development) is to extend the formats used in the `to_s` method:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!( 
  :russian => "%A %d %B %Y" 
) 

Time.now.to_s(:russian) #=> "Tuesday 17 February 2009"
```

Include the first bit in either `config/environment.rb` or in a file in `config/initializers`.